# Migrate localhost to server

Tags: migration, ftp

Good day!

How do you properly migrate your localhost wordpress file to a live server? What I do is usually copy all my wordpress file then transferred to my website thru FTP and the database is usually imported to the target sql.

The problem is when I do this, the website layout gets all messed up. I wanted to migrate my website without the layout being affected.

Thanks.

Comment: You can try WP Migrate DB plugin to export your database to move it to live. It will not break the site.

Comment: I would just use the export/import tools that come with WordPress.

Comment: @Valentin Genev that only transfers the content. Not the theme or the plugins or the plugin settings.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Ah, I see! So the other solutions should migrate everything even if the developer doesn't have FTP account?

Comment: @Bhupen I have tried using WP Migrate DB, not all is being transferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) too to rename your site's hostname safely and effectively. There's a chance that your layout is being messed up because naively replacing the domain name with a simple string replace, e.g. `perl -pi -e 's/oldhost/newhost/g' backup.sql`, will not take into account things like serialized data.

Try this on your local machine after install WP-CLI:

#### Using the `db-checkpoint` package:

```sh
wp package install binarygary/db-checkpoint
wp dbsnap pre-search-replace
wp search-replace --precise oldhost newhost
wp dbsnap post-search-replace
wp dbsnapback pre-search-replace
```

Now, take the file in `wp-content/uploads/checkpoint-storage` that starts with `post-search-replace` and import that to your remote host.

#### Without `db-checkpoint`:

```sh
# Backup your database here, this will be restored to your local once the
# operation is done
wp search-replace --precise oldhost newhost
# Take another backup now - this backup will go to your remote server
# Now, restore your original backup to have your local in a working state...
# OR do this:
wp search-replace --precise newhost oldhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to also change the **site URL** in your database under the **wp_options** table. And it should work.

Comment: I always make sure to do that yet my website still got this messy layout as opposed to my local website.

Comment: try to enable the debugger  and check if you get any errors

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ to move your entire site. It makes the process really easy and also takes care of any database replacements needed during migration.

Comment: I have tried duplicator, not migrating everything.