# Is it possible to migrate a wordpress website to another wordpress account?

Tags: migration

I have a website I developed on my own wordpress account and localhost. I uploaded this website on my clients hosting account using FTP. After uploading from localhost to live server,  I am unable to login to wordpress using client's credentials it simply shows unknown username whereas when I log in using my credentials it shows my wordpress admin dashboard. I want to transfer my website frommy account to clients wordpress account. How do I do it? I'm relatively new to wordpress so sorry if it seems like a trivial question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Migrate localhost to server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339413/migrate-localhost-to-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called either "Export and Import" or migration in Wordpress:

https://wpcrib.com/export-import-wordpress-website/

https://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/

https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/export-wordpress-site/